# How can I edit the Unreal FPS fire animation montage?

Tags: animation, unreal-engine4

The unreal first person firing animation montage pulls the arms too far back.

Is there a way to edit the firing montage so that I can reduce the amount of distance the animation pulls the arm back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, i don't think it's possible, because the montage is playing an animation on slots, etc... But you can't change the animation. You can find some animations online and replace it with the default one.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to export the animation into blender or some other 3d editing software and edit the animations to your liking and then simply reimport. There's no other way to edit the animation.

The only technique i know of and i am highly against it is simply try to change the animation blend in and out times so animation is transitioning out before it would come too far to back to the camera.